# Better way to grant access to data within a table based on user?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, database-design, database-normalization

I'm trying design a system for an API that grants users access to a data table Data based on a permission table Permissions which is related to a group table Group. When a user makes a request for data (from the Data table), my API should only return rows from the Data table based on the values within the columns of the Data table that they have been granted to
view.

By default, a user will have no access to any rows when requesting data through my API. However, I'd like to grant access to Data based on values in columns.

**For example** If my Data table contains information about news articles and has columns title, news_source, posted_date, and other similar columns

```
  id | title    |  news_source          | posted_date | ...
-----+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------
 1   | ...      | NYTimes               | 2019-12-30  |  
 2   | ...      | BBC                   | 2019-12-30  |  
 3   | ...      | BBC                   | 2019-12-30  |
 4   | ...      | Washington Post       | 2019-12-30  |
 5   | ...      | NYTimes               | 2019-12-30  |
 6   | ...      | NYTimes               | 2020-01-01  |
 7   | ...      | Boston Globe          | 2020-01-01  |
```

In this example, I'd like to grant a group access to get data only from NYTimes, posted after 2020-01-01, etc...

To do this, I've implemented the schema below

```
+-----+        +--------------+
|Group|<-------|Permission    |
+-----+        +--------------+
|name |        |group_id      |
|...  |        |column_name   |
+-----+        |text_value    |
               |date_value    |
               +--------------+
```

For Group, name is just the name of the group and the ellipse represents some other non-relevant columns. In Permissions, I have the foreign key to Group (group_id), the name of the column in the Data table that I'm accessing (column_name), and the value I'm granting access to (text_value or date_value depending on the column I'm referencing).

Right now, when a user makes a request for data, I run this SQL to apply the permissions (if the user's group has id = 1).

```
SELECT * FROM Data d
    INNER JOIN Permission p1 ON p1.group_id = 1 AND p1.column_name = 'news_source' AND p1.text_value = d.news_source
    INNER JOIN Permission p2 ON p2.group_id = 1 AND p2.column_name = 'posted_date' AND p2.date_value >= d.posted_date;
```

This will work, but I was wondering if there was a better more organized way to go about this. I feel there would be a lot of redundancy in this model across multiple groups with the same permissions.

Comment: Any reason why `perm` is not modeled with `(group_id, name, type)` for columns?

Comment: Field represents the column name and value is the value you'd check against in the Data table. 'name' and 'type' in Data would represent just two text columns since my Data table will have a bunch of different text columns if that makes sense. So 'field' is the column you're concerned with and 'value' is the column value you're checking against

Comment: Please provide actual test data representing rows from each table, the actual table definition including column name and data type, and the expected results form that data; all as text - **no images**.

Comment: See edits. I've hopefully described what I'm trying to do more clearly. Apologies for any confusion.